# Can image texture parameters be accessed from python?

Tags: python, scripting, image

I would like to create a new image texture and define its name and size entirely via Python. The closest I can get is to generate the popup window where I change these parameters. I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. Is this possible?

I'm trying to create a script that auto-bakes a color ID map, tied into a single fat "Bake" button. I want the image texture's name and size to be predefined when generated.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, nevermind! I found the answer almost immediately after posting.

```
bpy.data.images.new("StringName", 1024, 1024)
```

...I wasted an hour looking for this simple answer...